# How to start an Android app after downloading from a website?

Tags: android, apk

I upload an app to my website and it's: `domain.com/app.apk`. I want when user (on Android mobile) clicks the link that it would auto Open and Run App.

Answer (score 4):

You can not launch the application automatically. The user will download your app, and depending on the browser, it will launch the installer, or it will just download the apk, and the user needs to install it manually. But the apk needs to be installed always, and it will not be installed automatically. The user needs to acknowledge and confirm the application always (In a normal Android phone).

EDIT: As @Pewiity points in the comments below, the user needs to enable the `Install apps from unkown sources` in the phone.

Comment: Oh no, what's Language Program for do this? plz help me